# C# : Replace while loop with ForEach (Acrobat SDK)

Tags: c#, adobe, acrobat-sdk

Can this be replaced with ForEach or IEnumrable

```
 IAFormApp formApp = new AFormAppClass();    
 IFields myFields = (IFields)formApp.Fields;
 IEnumerator myEnumerator = myFields.GetEnumerator();
 while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
 { 
   IField myField = (IField)myEnumerator.Current;
 }
```

`myEnumerator.MoveNext()` is not iterating sequentially through my PDF Fields.

Comment: Can you specify your problem in more detail? Do you want to know how to convert a `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` into a `for each(...)`? Or do you have a problem with sequential processing?

Comment: what do you mean by `ForEach`? `List<T>.ForEach`? Then just don't do it.

Comment: @Caveman74. I am having  problem with sequential processing. I read somewhere that,If you would like to sequentially go through a collection, you should use the IEnumerable interface, not IEnumerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Adobe SDK API. But I think you are closer than you think. It seems that `IFields` is derived from `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<IField>`.

In C#, you can use [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) to iterate through a collection.

For example:

```cs
 IAFormApp formApp = new AFormAppClass();    
 IFields myFields = (IFields)formApp.Fields;
 
 foreach(IField field in myFields)
 {
   // do something with the field
 }
```

In the background, `foreach` uses `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` or the generic `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` to iterate over the elements in the collection. The mentioned method `GetEnumerator()` returns an `IEnumerator` respectively `IEnumerator<T>`.

You need to check where `IFields` is derived from. If it is derived from `IEnumerable<IField>`, you can use the example above. If it derives from `IEnumerable`, you need to convert the object to the desired object type, because `IEnumerator.Current` returns an object.

For more information on using `IEnumerable` or the generic form `IEnumerable<T>`, see the [C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators).